# Show that $X \perp\!\!\!\perp Y \iff \forall f \, \text{bounded and measurable} \, \mathbb{E}[f(X)\mid Y] = E[f(X)]$

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation, independence

I could only prove one direction, let $A \in \sigma(Y)$

$$\int_A\mathbb{E}[f(X)\mid Y] d\mathbb{P} =\int_Af(X) d\mathbb{P} = \mathbb{E}[f(X) \mathbb{1}_A]  =  \mathbb{E}[f(X)] \mathbb{E}[ \mathbb{1}_A] = \int_A  \mathbb{E}[f(X)]d\mathbb{P}$$

for third equality I used independence and every constant is measurable. so...

how to do the reverse implication though ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the opposite implication, let $A$ and $B$ be two Borel subsets of the real line. Using the assumption where $f$ is the indicator function of $A$, we get 
$$\tag{*}
\mathbb E\left[\mathbf 1_{A}\left(X\right)\mid Y\right]=\mathbb P\left(X\in A\right).
$$
By using the definition of conditional expectation with $\{Y\in B\}\in\sigma(B)$, 
we get that 
$$
\mathbb E\left[\mathbb E\left[\mathbf 1_{A}\left(X\right)\mid Y\right]\mathbf 1_B\left(Y\right)\right]=\mathbb E\left[ \mathbf 1_{A}\left(X\right)\mathbf 1_B\left(Y\right)\right]$$
and replacing $\mathbb E\left[\mathbf 1_{A}\left(X\right)\mid Y\right]$ by $\mathbb P\left(X\in A\right)$ gives the independence between $X$ and $Y$.

Observe also that a similar criterion can be established in order to show the independence between $X$ and a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal G$, namely, that for each measurable bounded function $f$, the equality 
$$
\mathbb E\left[f(X)\mid\mathcal G\right]=\mathbb E\left[f(X) \right]
$$
holds almost surely.